# Configuring Iosevka for Nix

Tags: configuration, nix, nixos

I'm trying to add the Iosevka font to my nix config. For that I [created a file fonts.nix](https://github.com/faeblDevelopment/nixconfig/blob/master/nixos/fonts.nix).
it cotains (amongst other things) a font array with this content:

```
fonts = with pkgs; [
  (iosevka.override {
    set = "custom";
    privateBuildPlan = {
    family = "Iosevka";
    design = [
      "common styles"
      "sans"
      "ligset-haskell"
    ] ++ cv;
    };
  })
  [...]
];
```

when i build the config though, nixos tells me the following:

```
error: anonymous function at [...]/nixos/pkgs/data/fonts/iosevka/default.nix:1:1 called with 
unexpected argument 'family', at [...]/nixos/lib/customisation.nix:69:16
```

as I have been unable to find documentation for the nix config, I used an exaple I [found](https://gitlab.com/luc65r/dotfiles) along with the [iosevka documentation](https://github.com/be5invis/Iosevka);

i tried removing the `privateBuildPlan` (then the same thing happens with `design`), i also tried moving the `family` out of the `privateBuildPlan` and keeping the rest as it is (same result as the first error).

however, I can't get it working; 
do you have any tipps or maybe a link to the documentation of the nix iosevka package? the package on nixos.org just links to the normal iosevka github where I couldn't find anything...

Comment: The error message you posted only makes sense when `family` is moved outside, which is wrong; your code as posted, with `family` inside `privateBuildPlan`, works for me. As for documentation, there is one tiny example in the derivation source: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/data/fonts/iosevka/default.nix#L7-L14

Answer (score -2):

Here is what I use:

```
  fonts = {
    fontconfig = {
      # ultimate.enable = true; # This enables fontconfig-ultimate settings for better font rendering
      defaultFonts = {
        monospace = ["Iosevka"];
      };
    };
    enableFontDir = true;
    enableGhostscriptFonts = true;
    fonts = with pkgs; [
      terminus_font
      corefonts
      noto-fonts
      iosevka
    ];
  };
```

Which seems to be documented here: https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Fonts